# Exit the program when FileNotFound: [Win Error 3] arises

Tags: python, operating-system, global-variables

I am using a for loop to look for various files. Somes when the file with specific is not found, the program stops immediately and raises the Filenotfound error. Instead, I want the program to exit safely when such errors arise.
My code:

```
os.chdir('FileLocation')
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
```

Present output:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:....//2016//01'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try:
    dosomething()
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass
    ...
```

Comment: how do I break the for loop if there is one?

Comment: with `break`: https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/simple_stmts.html#break